# SpriteKit: blurred background SKNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sknode, skview, skeffectnode

How can I blur the background of a single transparent SKNode, while leaving the main background clear? I want something like this:

[image]

The background is a single root SKNode and there's another SKNode added as a child. The child node is transparent and has a blur effect.

I want to use a SKEffectNode to produce the blur, but an SKEffectNode blurs a child node, and in this case I need the **parent** (root node) to be blurred.

Additionally, this is more complicated because the blurred background below is subject to physics simulation and can move, so the background blur needs to update live if that's possible.

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490818/how-do-i-blur-a-scene-in-spritekit) describe blurring the whole background, while this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24999885/1161906) combines the SKEffectNode with a SKCropNode. I feel like this is on the right track, but I'm not sure what the hierarchy should be, since again the SKEffectNode needs to operate on a child.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yup, need to do the same. Anyone had any luck?